# How to add URL before word in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table that row is

```
ID    Twitter                             Facebook                   UserID
1      @kamel                              http:www.fb.com/rtymal       10
2      http:www.twitter.com/rlyill         makmal                       170
3      ymikll                              mtymal                       15
4      @wiled                              makfrl                       13
```

I need to add `http:www.twitter.com` for all row that not have it. Same as for facebook.

So in the table I need result like

```
ID    Twitter                             Facebook                   UserID
1      http:www.twitter.com/kamel     http:www.fb.com/rtymal           10
2      http:www.twitter.com/rlyill    http:www.fb.com/makmal           170
3      http:www.twitter.com/ymikll    http:www.fb.com/mtymal           15
4      http:www.twitter.com/wiled     http:www.fb.com/makfrl           13
```

Comment: first of all this not enough information to get your question,show us your code what have you tried.

Comment: you should know that the URL that you've saved isn't strictly correct - it should be `http://` not just `http:` though Chrome seems to accept just  `http:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the table contents:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Twitter = concat('http:www.twitter.com/', Twitter)
WHERE Twitter not like 'http:www.twitter.com%'
```

If you just want to modify a result-set, do similar thing in a select:

```
select case when Twitter not like 'http:www.twitter.com%' then
                concat('http:www.twitter.com/', Twitter) else  Twitter end
from tablename
```

Comment: Oops, missed removal of @, which can made with Twitter = replace(Twitter,'@','')

Comment: thanks, But somerow have @wiled .. when use your sql its show me http:www.twitter.com@wiled

Comment: The concat should be `concat('http:www.twitter.com/', Twitter)`

Comment: @Sathya, sorry, missed that. The answer is now edited.

Comment: Congrats on 1k rep, btw :)